# Importing ntlk getting a error like this on CentOS.7

Tags: centos, centos7, python

Importing NTLK in Centos7.3 I am getting error like this

SQLite is getting installed but I am still getting error

enter code here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from nltk.translate import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/translate/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score as meteor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/translate/meteor_score.py", line 10, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 32, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/panlex_lite.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3
```

'

Answer (score 0):

check the **pip list** and if module is not there you try like below to install.

```
python<version> -m pip install --user -U pysqlite3
```

If still not work try to install libsqlite3-dev and compile from the start python3.7(which is used by you per logs) to make it work.